# Decorating Multiple Python Functions

Tags: python, python-decorators

Let's say I have many pairs of complementary functions:

```
def comp_func1(arg1, arg2):
    return f"comp_func1 {arg1} {arg2}"

def func1(arg1, arg2, flag=True):
    if flag:
        return f"func1 {arg1} {arg2}"
    else:
        return comp_func1(arg1, arg2)

def comp_func2(arg1, arg2):
    return f"comp_func2 {arg1} {arg2}"

def func2(arg1, arg2, flag=True):
    if flag:
        return f"func2 {arg1} {arg2}"
    else:
        return comp_func2(arg1, arg2)
```

Essentially, for each function `funcX`, if `flag == True` then it will return the function details but if `flag == False` then it will call its complementary function, `comp_funcX`, which returns the complementary function details.

Instead of having to use `if`/`else` statements in each `funcX`, is it possible to use decorators to clean up or simplify this code? Something along the lines of:

```
def decorator():
    """
    Check the `flag` and choose whether to call the complementary function
    """
    def wrapper():
        if flag:
            return func(arg1, arg2)
        else:
            return comp_func(args, arg2) 
    return wrapper

def comp_func1(arg1, arg2):
    return f"comp_func1 {arg1} {arg2}"

@decorator(comp_func1)
def func1(arg1, arg2, flag=True):
    return f"func1 {arg1} {arg2}"

def comp_func2(arg1, arg2):
    return f"comp_func2 {arg1} {arg2}"

@decorator(comp_func2)
def func2(arg1, arg2, flag=True):
    return f"func2 {arg1} {arg2}"
```

Comment: Except for some missing details in your decorator, you didn't say what's wrong with it. It seems like you're looking for alternate solutions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def some_decorator(comp_function):
    def decorator_with_argument(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if kwargs.get("flag", False):
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return comp_function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator_with_argument


def comp_func1(arg1, arg2, *_, **__):
    return f"comp_func1 {arg1} {arg2}"


@some_decorator(comp_func1)
def func1(arg1, arg2, *_, **__):
    return f"func1 {arg1} {arg2}"
```

The `wrapper` function usually takes `*args` and `**kwargs`, so it is more general.

Comment: Ah, I was too slow in writing my answer! You have got `function` and `comp_function` flipped, though. `some_decorator` should take `comp_function` as an argument and `decorator_with_argument` should take `function`.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the arguments of `func1` inside of `wrapper`, I would suggest changing `flag` in `func1` into a keyword-only argument: `func1(arg1, arg2, *, flag=True):` and then changing `wrapper`to: `def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):` with a `kwargs.get("flag", False)` if-statement instead.

Answer (score -1):

A slightly different approach is to use a simple wrapper function instead of a full-fledged decorator. Pack all the functions and complementary ones in corresponding lists, and call your functions through the wrapper with the index:

```py
funcs = [func1, func2, ...]
comps = [comp_func1, comp_func2, ...]

def wrapper(i, arg1, arg2, flag):
    if flag:
        return funcs[i-1](arg1, arg2)
    else:
        return comps[i-1](arg1, arg2)
```

And now to call `func1` you simply call:

```
wrapper(1, arg1, arg2, flag)
```

---

This is based on the functions implemented as in the second code-block. i.e. each function returns its corresponding data - no `flag` condition inside them.